# Why isn't my php page found? Is it an issue with my yaml file?

Tags: php, html, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am currently working on an interface to run SQL queries to my mySQL database on the google cloud platform. I have PHP, HTML, and YAML files. I have gotten my HTML to launch, but for some reason, every time I try run the query, I am taken to this page:[HTML Error 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9X5F.png)

I don't think it is the PHP or HTML that is the issue because when I added a test HTML button, that worked on my local machine. My yaml file is this:

```
service: default
runtime: php55

handlers:

- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1

- url: /$
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
```

Does anyone understand if there is something I am doing wrong in this configuration? My php file is called sql.php and the main html file is called index.html Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You would also need to define your [**environment variables**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/reference/app-yaml#defining_environment_variables) in the **app.yaml** file.

Here is an **example** from GCP [GitHub repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/php55/cloudsql/app.yaml):

```
# [START gae_php_mysql_env]
env_variables:
  # Replace USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE, and CONNECTION_NAME with the
  # values obtained when configuring your Cloud SQL instance.
  MYSQL_DSN: mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME;dbname=DATABASE
  MYSQL_USER: USER
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: PASSWORD
# [END gae_php_mysql_env]
```

> **Remember** - storing secrets in plaintext is potentially unsafe. Consider using something like https://cloud.google.com/kms/ to help
>   keep secrets secret.

Comment: Thank you, but I am still having the same issue when I add that in. I have used this page (https://medium.com/@kerion7/creating-a-simple-php-application-on-google-app-engine-c75ce5150c30) as guidance but he seems to be making an app in a flex environment and I think mine needs to be static.

Comment: Could you confirm that you have one of the following roles enabled in your GAE service account: **Cloud SQL Client**, **Cloud SQL Editor**, **Cloud SQL Admin**?